# Unable to Connect to Oracle database on server from Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Created a fresh spring boot startup project. I am trying to connect one of the oracle DB server with the spring boot but end up having the below error.

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:628) ~[ojdbc8-21.1.0.0.jar:21.1.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:557) ~[ojdbc8-21.1.0.0.jar:21.1.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:552) ~[ojdbc8-21.1.0.0.jar:21.1.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:1312) ~[ojdbc8-21.1.0.0.jar:21.1.0.0.0]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to detect database type
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76) ~[spring-core-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.init.PlatformPlaceholderDatabaseDriverResolver.determinePlatform(PlatformPlaceholderDatabaseDriverResolver.java:132) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
```

Although I am able to connect via SQL. I have the following configuration as of now in the application.properties, I have the following

```
server.port=8080
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@100.73.35.145:1521/pdborcl
spring.datasource.username=DP1MT1_FAWAPPSHEL
spring.datasource.password=welcome1
spring.sql.init.platform=oracle
spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
```

In POM.xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.playpause</groupId>
    <artifactId>zdt-batch-job</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>zdt-batch-job</name>
    <description>Batch Application</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>21.1.0.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Please provide any inputs which can help on this.

Comment: What is the version of Oracle Database?

Comment: Version is 21.0.0.0